# Flutter Dart Sqflite facing problem with handling data types inside onCreate method in Sqflite

Tags: sql, flutter, sqlite, dart, retrofit

How to create an onCreate method for a Sqflite database in Flutter using the RocketResponse model?

I am using retrofit for RestAPI, Riverpod for state management, and Sqflite for Localdb.

I am having trouble defining data types in the onCreate method in Sqflite.

The below code is of the Modal class that I have used for creating the SQLite database.

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

import '../entity/diameter.dart';
import '../entity/engines.dart';
import '../entity/first_stage.dart';
import '../entity/landing_legs.dart';
import '../entity/mass.dart';
import '../entity/payload_weights.dart';
import '../entity/second_stage.dart';

part 'rocket_response.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class RocketResponse {
  final Diameter height;
  final Diameter diameter;
  final Mass mass;
  @JsonKey(name: 'first_stage')
  final FirstStage firstStage;
  @JsonKey(name: 'second_stage')
  final SecondStage secondStage;
  final Engines engines;
  @JsonKey(name: 'landing_legs')
  final LandingLegs landingLegs;
  @JsonKey(name: 'payload_weights')
  final List<PayloadWeight> payloadWeights;
  @JsonKey(name: 'flickr_images')
  final List<String> flickrImages;
  final String name;
  final String type;
  final bool active;
  final int stages;
  final int boosters;
  @JsonKey(name: 'cost_per_launch')
  final int costPerLaunch;
  @JsonKey(name: 'success_rate_pct')
  final int successRatePct;
  @JsonKey(name: 'first_flight')
  final DateTime firstFlight;
  final String country;
  final String company;
  final String wikipedia;
  final String description;
  final String id;

  RocketResponse({
    required this.height,
    required this.diameter,
    required this.mass,
    required this.firstStage,
    required this.secondStage,
    required this.engines,
    required this.landingLegs,
    required this.payloadWeights,
    required this.flickrImages,
    required this.name,
    required this.type,
    required this.active,
    required this.stages,
    required this.boosters,
    required this.costPerLaunch,
    required this.successRatePct,
    required this.firstFlight,
    required this.country,
    required this.company,
    required this.wikipedia,
    required this.description,
    required this.id,
  });

  factory RocketResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$RocketResponseFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$RocketResponseToJson(this);
}

import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'mass.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Mass {
  final int kg;
  final int lb;

  Mass({
    required this.kg,
    required this.lb,
  });

  factory Mass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$MassFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$MassToJson(this);
}

import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'diameter.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Diameter {
  final double? meters;
  final double? feet;

  Diameter({
    this.meters,
    this.feet,
  });

  factory Diameter.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$DiameterFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$DiameterToJson(this);
}

import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'package:spacex_rockets/network/entity/thrust.dart';

part 'first_stage.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class FirstStage {
  @JsonKey(name: 'thrust_sea_level')
  final Thrust thrustSeaLevel;
  @JsonKey(name: 'thrust_vacuum')
  final Thrust thrustVacuum;
  final bool reusable;
  final int engines;
  @JsonKey(name: 'fuel_amount_tons')
  final double fuelAmountTons;
  @JsonKey(name: 'burn_time_sec')
  final int? burnTimeSec;

  FirstStage({
    required this.thrustSeaLevel,
    required this.thrustVacuum,
    required this.reusable,
    required this.engines,
    required this.fuelAmountTons,
    this.burnTimeSec,
  });

  factory FirstStage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$FirstStageFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$FirstStageToJson(this);
}

import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'package:spacex_rockets/network/entity/payloads.dart';
import 'package:spacex_rockets/network/entity/thrust.dart';

part 'second_stage.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class SecondStage {
  final Thrust thrust;
  final Payloads payloads;
  final bool reusable;
  final int engines;
  @JsonKey(name: 'fuel_amount_tons')
  final double fuelAmountTons;
  @JsonKey(name: 'burn_time_sec')
  final int? burnTimeSec;

  SecondStage({
    required this.thrust,
    required this.payloads,
    required this.reusable,
    required this.engines,
    required this.fuelAmountTons,
    this.burnTimeSec,
  });

  factory SecondStage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$SecondStageFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$SecondStageToJson(this);
}

import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'thrust.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Thrust {
  final int kN;
  final int lbf;

  Thrust({
    required this.kN,
    required this.lbf,
  });

  factory Thrust.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ThrustFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ThrustToJson(this);
}

import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

import 'composite_fairing.dart';

part 'payloads.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Payloads {
  @JsonKey(name: 'composite_fairing')
  final CompositeFairing compositeFairing;
  @JsonKey(name: 'option_1')
  final String option1;

  Payloads({
    required this.compositeFairing,
    required this.option1,
  });

  factory Payloads.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$PayloadsFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PayloadsToJson(this);
}

import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'package:spacex_rockets/network/entity/thrust.dart';

import 'isp.dart';

part 'engines.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Engines {
  final Isp isp;
  @JsonKey(name: 'thrust_sea_level')
  final Thrust thrustSeaLevel;
  @JsonKey(name: 'thrust_vacuum')
  final Thrust thrustVacuum;
  final int number;
  final String type;
  final String version;
  final String? layout;
  @JsonKey(name: 'engine_loss_max')
  final int? engineLossMax;
  @JsonKey(name: 'propellant_1')
  final String propellant1;
  @JsonKey(name: 'propellant_2')
  final String propellant2;
  @JsonKey(name: 'thrust_to_weight')
  final double thrustToWeight;

  Engines({
    required this.isp,
    required this.thrustSeaLevel,
    required this.thrustVacuum,
    required this.number,
    required this.type,
    required this.version,
    this.layout,
    this.engineLossMax,
    required this.propellant1,
    required this.propellant2,
    required this.thrustToWeight,
  });

  factory Engines.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$EnginesFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$EnginesToJson(this);
}

import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'isp.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Isp {
  @JsonKey(name: 'sea_level')
  final int seaLevel;
  final int vacuum;

  Isp({
    required this.seaLevel,
    required this.vacuum,
  });

  factory Isp.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$IspFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$IspToJson(this);
}

import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'landing_legs.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class LandingLegs {
  final int number;
  final String? material;

  LandingLegs({
    required this.number,
    this.material,
  });

  factory LandingLegs.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$LandingLegsFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$LandingLegsToJson(this);
}

import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'payload_weights.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class PayloadWeight {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final int kg;
  final int lb;

  PayloadWeight({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.kg,
    required this.lb,
  });

  factory PayloadWeight.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$PayloadWeightFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PayloadWeightToJson(this);
}
```

Rocket Database using Sqflite

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' as path_provider;
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

import '../network/response/rocket_response.dart';

class RocketDatabase {
  static final RocketDatabase _instance = RocketDatabase._internal();

  factory RocketDatabase() => _instance;

  RocketDatabase._internal();

  static Database? _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) {
      return _database!;
    }

    _database = await _initDatabase();
    return _database!;
  }

  Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    final documentsDirectory =
        await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final path = join(documentsDirectory.path, 'rocket_database.db');

    return await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: 1,
      onCreate: _createTables,
    );
  }

  //I'm having a problem with defining the data types here!
  Future<void> _createTables(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''
      CREATE TABLE rockets (
        id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    height REAL,
diameter REAL,
    mass REAL,
first_stage TEXT,
    second_stage TEXT,
engines TEXT,
    landing_legs TEXT,
payload_weights TEXT,
    flickr_images TEXT,
name TEXT,
    type TEXT,
active INTEGER,
    stages INTEGER,
boosters INTEGER,
    cost_per_launch INTEGER,
success_rate_pct INTEGER,
    first_flight INTEGER,
country TEXT,
    company TEXT,
wikipedia TEXT,
    description TEXT
      )
    ''');
  }

  Future<void> clearRockets() async {
    final db = await database;
    await db.delete('rockets');
  }

  Future<void> insertRockets(List<RocketResponse> rockets) async {
    final db = await database;
    final batch = db.batch();

    for (final rocket in rockets) {
      batch.insert('rockets', rocket.toJson());
    }

    await batch.commit();
  }

  Future<List<RocketResponse>> getRockets() async {
    final db = await database;
    final maps = await db.query('rockets');
    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) => RocketResponse.fromJson(maps[i]));
  }
}
```

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start - _if_ you're having SQL problems.